# Setting Matlab source control preferences

Tags: windows, matlab

I am using MATLAB R2013b in Windows 8.1 64-bit. I was trying to let MATLAB reopen files in editor that I had been previously working on. But checking *'Preferences > Editor/Debugger > On restart reopen files from previous MATLAB session'* did not work. Anybody knows how to do it??

In *'Preferences > General > Source Control,'* there is no source control system but a warning saying *"You are running a 64-bit version of MATLAB, which does not support 32-bit source control systems."*

I assume the absence of source control system makes it impossible to save my preferences.

Am I correct? If so, how should I fix my MATLAB?

Thank you.

Comment: No, there is no relation between the source control systems and the ability to save preferences.